# Xmlsec library to implement Django SAML2 Authentication

Tags: python, django, saml, windows-server, xmlsec

I'll use this Django package to integrate SAML2 Authentication into my django APP : https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth.

This package requires `xmlsec libary`, unfortunately i am using windows server where i will install this library.

I've tried to install it in windows by following the documentation :

- I got the library here : https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/download.html
- I got windows binaries from here : https://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/64bit/

After following the documentation to install this libary on windows :

i could configure the install by : `cscript configure.js prefix=c:\opt include=c:\opt\include lib=c:\opt\lib debug=yes`

```
This is the result : 

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


libxmlsec version: 1.2.29
Created Makefile.

XMLSEC configuration
----------------------------
         Use Crypto: openssl
 Use Default Crypto: openssl
        Use OpenSSL: Enabled
Use OpenSSL Version: 110
            Use NSS: Disabled
       Use MSCrypto: Disabled
          Use MSCng: Disabled
        Use LibXSLT: Enabled
          Use iconv: Enabled
     NT 4.0 support: Enabled

Win32 build configuration
-------------------------
  C-Runtime option: /MD
           Unicode: Enabled
     Debug symbols: Enabled
Warnings as errors: Disabled
        C compiler: cl.exe
  C compiler flags:
     Static xmlsec: Enabled
 Enable DL support: Enabled
    Install prefix: c:\opt
      Put tools in: $(PREFIX)\bin
    Put headers in: $(PREFIX)\include
Put static libs in: $(PREFIX)\lib
Put shared libs in: $(PREFIX)\bin
      Include path: c:\opt\include
          Lib path: c:\opt\lib
```

i've put the binaries in the folders above.
After i've run the make file by using `nmake`
Here the result :

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libxml2.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe"' : return code '0x450'
```

So i don't know what to do to continue my installing, i've followed the documentation maybe i missed something.

Anyone can help please

Thank you